# JavaScript's html setter "eats" leading linebreak inside textarea - how to overcome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, line-breaks

**SOLVED**

*The problem is solved in a tricky way. The answer is posted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13771283/1102014).*

---

I have a textarea control with `white-space: pre;` style, which works perfectly well while editing new stuff, storing it into a database (intact, with `\r\n`), and displaying as an inline part of html page (inside a div with the same style).

The problem occurs when I try to edit such text in a popup dialog with the same textarea feeded from AJAX response. I'm trying to assign received text into the textarea by means of jQuery:

```
$('#textfield').html(text);
```

Actually the whole dialog with filled in textarea is received in the response.

Unfortunately, this html-setter removes leading linebreak. Is there a way to eliminate such inconsistent behaviour? Linebreaks which occur further in content are presaved normally.

Example of html code, received from the server:

```
<textarea id="newtext" cols="60" rows="3" style="white-space:pre;">
Text with line break at its start.
More line break</textarea>
```

After placing the code by means of `html` into container, I got exactly this:

```
<textarea id="newtext" cols="60" rows="3" style="white-space:pre;">Text with line break at its start.
More line break</textarea>
```

P.S. More code added from the context, though I don't think this may help somehow:

**JavaScript:**

```
var d = $('#dialog');

console.log(msg); // correct data
console.log('==============');

d.html(msg).css({position: "absolute", top: (pos.top + height) + "px", left: (pos.left + width) + "px"});

console.log(d.html()); // corrupted data

d.show();
$('#newtext').focus();
```

**HTML with container**:

```
<div id="dialog" class="popup">
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

As @Pointy suggested, it's indeed not jQuery's issue. I replaced the html-setter to the plain old:

```
document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = msg;
```

and got the same problem. Browser is Chrome. Can't test other browsers right now.

Comment: have you tried text instead of html?like this $('#textfield').text(text);

Comment: I have html inside, so I can't use `text`.

Comment: You should set the value of `<textarea>` elements with `.val()`, not `.html()`

Comment: @Pointy - You should write an `answer` not a `comment` :)

Comment: @Pointy, I added more info into the question. It should be `html`, cause it's applied for container, not textarea itself.

Comment: It may not be jQuery that's doing it - it may be the normal way a browser works.

Comment: @Pointy, ok, i'll check this. Anyway, I don't find this normal way, because it breaks data consistency.

Comment: It may be that way to allow for a line break between the opening `<textarea>` tag and the first line of content. That is, it's to make the markup loop better.  I agree that it introduces the very problem you're having :-)

Comment: For what it's worth, when you directly set the value of the textarea element, the browser does not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a workaround, very simple one. Into the original HTML code of the textarea:

```
<textarea id="newtext" cols="60" rows="3" style="white-space:pre;"><?php echo $templateVariablePlaceholder; ?></textarea>
```

I added a linebreak after opening tag:

```
<textarea id="newtext" cols="60" rows="3" style="white-space:pre;">
<?php echo $templateVariablePlaceholder; ?></textarea>
```

Now it works, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually using a `<textarea>`, use .val instead of .html.

Edit - maybe this is a bit closer to what you need, if you're inserting things here and there...

```
var textarea = $("<textarea>").val(query);
$(".div-container").append(textarea);
//or, if you're going to replace the one in there
$(".div-container textarea").replaceWith(textarea)
```

Basically the point is that you can assign a variable with a jquery reference to the textarea and then you can take that and put it anywhere you need it.

Comment: I edited my question. textarea - is a part of html, which is inserted into div-container. This is why I use `html`.

Comment: OK - so, to be clear, you're creating a textarea and inserting it into a div-container? And the textarea is what is losing the linebreaks?

Comment: Yes, the textarea looses leading linebreak (it is exists).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't send text on its own. I'm sending entire popup dialog.

Comment: Can you post some more code about what you're doing then? Otherwise we could be at this all day..

Comment: Pardon, do you mean html-code or javascript? It's almost all involved. Let me know which details seem important to you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do `text = text.match(/[^\n]+/g).join('<br>');` before using `.html(text)` to replace new lines with `<br>`s?

Comment: Tried that. Breaks are inserted and visible in the textarea as text. Moreover, excessive breaks (from html code formatting) screw up the dialog itself.

Comment: I thought it was in a div and not a textarea?

Comment: textarea is a part of dialog inserted into a div-container.

Comment: As I wrote above, val is not applicable, because I set html of entire dialog.

Comment: Can you parse out the `textarea` from the HTML before appending it, then append the `textarea` to the dialog DOM object? A different approach, but one that may be needed here due to the conflicting requirements.

Comment: I've posted a simple solution.

Comment: Will do in 2 days. SO does not allow accepting own answers so fast.